# How to edit user permission in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am following the tutorial of [django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/). I want to add user-based permission so that only authenticated user can view each user's detail information.
Objective : Anyone can view the UserList, but only owner can view its UserDetail.

#### models.py

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        sinceWhen = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        tilWhen = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='meetings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        #highlighted = models.TextField()

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(Meeting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


        class Meta:
                ordering = ('created',)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# User is not created inside models.py

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
# I added IsOwnerOrReadOnly to make it work, but this is the part where it causes error!
```

#### serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        meetings = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Meeting.objects.all())
        #owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ('id', 'username', 'meetings',)

class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        #meetings = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Meeting.objects.all())

        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ('username',)
```

#### permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):  
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

                # Any permissions are only allowed to the owner of the meeting
                return obj.owner == request.user
```

I overrode IsOwnerOrReadOnly so that only user can view the details of his/her user detail.
And add this to permission_class in views.py.

Then I got this error :

```
File "/home/tony/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in check_object_permissions
  345.             if not permission.has_object_permission(request, self, obj):

File "/home/tony/swpp_hw1/meetings/permissions.py" in has_object_permission
  15.       return obj.owner == request.user

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/1/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'owner'
```

I tried to add User class in models.py, but again it causes error...
How can solve this issue?

Comment: There is no `owner` on the `User` model. There is a reverse relationship named `meetings` to a `Meeting` model.

> Anyone can view the UserList, but only owner can view its UserDetail.

Your permission class just needs to test that `obj == request.user`. That means that the user that is being looked up is equal to the user that is performing the lookup. The meeting ownership will be handled inherently due to the data model i.e. The user detail view will only show meetings that the looked up user owns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it as:

```
return obj == request.user
```

as `object` is user you are trying to access and `request.user` is current authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks. Only use it with UserSerializer class.